# React select onChange is getting triggered for the second time with old value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am using React Select to show list of items . On change of item , i want to show a warning based on some flag . If flag is true , Dialog box will be displayed and and confirm of that , I want to allow the change . For every on on change , i am storing the selected item in local state use effect . On click of confirm from dialog box or if flag is false , i am dispatching actions to store them in redux store .

I am having issue when Dialog box is appearing and on click of confirm, item in dropdown is changing , but onChange is getting called again with first value ,Hence dropdown is going back to initial value .

Why is onChange getting called twice .

Tried event.preventDefault , but not working.

```
const [name, setName] = React.useState();

const changeValue = (event,selectedItem) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setName(selectedItem) // storing in UseState hook 
    if(flag){
        props.toggleWarningDialog(true);
    }
    else {
        props.onChangeItem(selectedItem);
    }
}

const handleConfirmChange = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        props.onChangeItem(name); //getting from useState hook and storing in redux by dispatching an action
 }
```

Comment: confusing. What is calling changeValue? can u show the components?

Comment: It's not clear how things are wired together, but if `changeValue()` and `handleConfirmChange()` are being called in succession, keep in mind that `setName(selectedItem)` happens asynchronously. So if you're relying on `props.onChangeItem(name)` to use an updated value of `name`, it might not.

Comment: What `onChange` are you referring to? Please update to include all relevant code you've an issue working with. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ChangeValue() is called in OnChange in React select .When ever item in drop down is changed, OnChange will e called which inturn call ChangeValue ()

Answer (score 0):

`stopPropagation` prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.
We can use `event.isPropagationStopped()` to determine if this method was ever called (on that event object).
Note that this will not prevent other handlers on the same element from running.

```
event.stopPropagation();
```